# How to connect to aws serverless MySQL cluster using the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk, aws-serverless

I created a serverless MySQL cluster on AWS, using AWS CDK, the following way.

```js
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'AuroraVPC');  

 const cluster = new rds.ServerlessCluster(this, 'test-cluster', {
            engine: rds.DatabaseClusterEngine.AURORA_MYSQL,
            vpc, // this parameter is optional for serverless Clusters
            enableDataApi: true, // Optional - will be automatically set if you call grantDataApiAccess()
            defaultDatabaseName: 'testDatabase'
          });
```

- the endpoint is:`teststack-testauroraclusterrdecluster84564799-s1bpkbop6jqx.cluster-cqpknxe6ocwv.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`
- the port is `3306`
- My account number is `123456789253`

I tried to connect using the cluster via the terminal but couldn't.

How can I connect it via the my mac terminal?
`mysql -h ? -u ? -p`

Thanks!

Comment: `mysql -h rdestack-rdeauroraclusterrdecluster84564799-s1bpkbop6jqx.cluster-cqpknxe6ocwv.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -u <whatever user you specified as the MySQL admin user when you created the server in RDS> -p`

Comment: What would be my password then?

Comment: I haven't specified admin on my code

Comment: Your database currently doesn't have a user. It looks like there is an optional `credentials` parameter that you need to pass into `rds.ServerlessCluster()` to create an admin user account.

Comment: I added credentials. It still doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't work **how**? Be specific. What is the error now?